# DateDiff and Continuous periods

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I need to see if one date span, in number of days, matches that of two date spans that cover the same period, but are added together.

For example...

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE
(
    Id INT,
    StartDate DATETIME,
    EndDate DATETIME
)
INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES (1, '2015-07-01 00:00:00.000', '2016-06-30 00:00:00.000')

DECLARE @Table2 TABLE
(
    Id INT,
    Fk INT,
    StartDate DATETIME,
    EndDate DATETIME
)
INSERT INTO @Table2 VALUES (1, 1, '2015-07-01', '2015-08-31')
INSERT INTO @Table2 VALUES (2, 1, '2015-09-01', '2016-03-31')
INSERT INTO @Table2 VALUES (3, 1, '2016-04-01', NULL)

SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, T1.StartDate, T1.EndDate) AS SiteContractDays,
    DATEDIFF(DAY, T2.StartDate, ISNULL(T2.EndDate, T1.EndDate)) AS SummedDayes
FROM @Table1 t1
INNER JOIN @Table2 t2
ON t2.fk = t1.Id

SELECT T1.Id, DATEDIFF(DAY, T1.StartDate, T1.EndDate) AS SiteContractDays,
    SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY, T2.StartDate, ISNULL(T2.EndDate, T1.EndDate))) AS SummedDayes
FROM @Table1 t1
INNER JOIN @Table2 t2
ON t2.fk = t1.Id
GROUP BY T1.id, T1.StartDate, T1.EndDate
```

Dates are continuous.. they follow on for the full period. However, when I sum them up, we're short a few days. I'm not sure I can simply add a day to each DateDiff, because... then the total goes to 366, and the summed up values will go up as well.

I could add `" + COUNT(*) -1 AS"` to the SUM of the days when grouping them up, but that seems like a hack.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: 1459 is correct because you started counting again from 2016-07-01 which starts from 02 as day 1

Comment: So 2016-07-01 isn't being included in the count? But it's starting from 2016-07-02?

Comment: nope.. your day 1 will restart from 02

Comment: Yes, you just need to add one day, because DATEDIFF is a measurement in the difference of a unit (whether it be a day, a minute, an hour or something else) between two dates. So, for example, the date difference of days between today's date and tomorrow's date is 1 because the numerical unit for the day will be X+1 - X.

Comment: OK, I still don't see how this is happening. I've edited the question to put a full example. It's runnable. Totals don't match.

Comment: i don't get if you get how to count with breaks and without... the problem is simple but you are making it complicated.

Comment: if you work from 8am to 12nn without a break that's 4 hours but if you are working from 8am to 10am (break 1 hour) and start again from 11am to 12noon so how many hours did you work for? 3 hours

Comment: @maSTAShuFu - This issue is around contracts. A person has a contract from the the 1st until the 10th... inclusive. The contract is split between two different phases. The 1st phase is from the 1st until the 5th, inclusive. The 2nd is from the 6th until the 10th.. inclusive. All days covered. The sum of those phases... should equal the contract. But it doesn't. There's no breaks... it's a continuous date.... 1st to the 5th... 6th to the 10th.

Comment: i think you have an issue with your contracts dates... it should be 1st to 5th, 5th to 10th, 10th to 15th and so on... thus you still count continuous

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the + 1 is better but if you calculate by seconds it will be 1460 days in the end

```
SELECT (DATEDIFF(SECOND, '2015-07-01 00:00:00', '2016-06-30 23:59:59') + DATEDIFF(SECOND, '2016-07-01 00:00:00', '2019-06-30  23:59:59')) / 60 / 60 / 24  
-- 1460
```

Answer (score 0):

Two different statements that you need to understand.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, '2015-07-01 00:00:00.000', '2019-06-30 00:00:00.000') -- 1460
```

No break thus count is continuous from day 1.
Day 1 from 2015-07-02

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, '2015-07-01', '2016-06-30') + DATEDIFF(DAY, '2016-07-01', '2019-06-30 00:00:00.000') -- 1459
```

Two different starting dates thus two different day 1s so you won't assume this is continuous...

day 1 from 2015-07-02 and day 1 from 2016-07-02...  Day between 2016-06-30 and 2016-07-01 is your break and not counted.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps in breaking periods, you always need to add that 1 missing second explicitly.

```
SELECT 
DATEDIFF(DAY, '2015-07-01 00:00:00.000', '2016-06-30') + 
DATEDIFF(DAY, '2016-07-01', DATEADD(SECOND,1,'2019-06-30 23:59:59.000')) --1460
```